# Error caused by conflict between gtk2 and gtk3 after compiling

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, and I have the following program from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html):

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    static void
    activate (GtkApplication* app,
            gpointer        user_data)
    {
        GtkWidget *window;

        window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
        gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
        gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
        gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    }

    int
    main (int    argc,
            char **argv)
    {
        GtkApplication *app;
        int status;

        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
        status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref (app);

        return status;
    }
```

and I compile it with:

```
    $ gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-0 example-0.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

everything goes well until I run

```
    $ ./example-0
```

I got the result:

```
    (example-0:12451): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
    Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have gtk+-2.0 installed before gtk+-3.0 was installed, after the error was reported, I removed gtk+-2.0 by the following command:

```
    $ sudo apt-get purge libgtk-2-dev
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove libgtk-2-dev
```

but that doesn't help, how to fix the problem now.

Comment: I reckon your issue is the application name `org.gtk.example`; try using a different name?

Comment: @andlabs I tried this `app = gtk_application_new ("this.is.another_name", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);`, but still the same error.

Comment: Can you run `echo gcc \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0\` -o example-0 example-0.c \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0\``?

Comment: @andlabs the result is: `gcc -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -o example-0 example-0.c -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0`

Comment: Any update here.